# How hard is recovering a binary matrix from its check sums?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity

I am interested in combinatorial (worst-case) one-way functions. I came across this problem which may be related to coding theory problems (I am not an expert in coding theory).

**INPUT**: Two vectors $R_{n*1}$ and $C_{1*n}$.

**QUESTION**: Is there a binary matrix $A_{n*n}$ such that vector $R$ contains the parity check of each row in $A$ and vector $C$ contains the parity check of each column in $A$.

The parity check of a row (or column) is the sum of all bits Mod 2 (XOR operation).

> What is the time complexity of this problem? Is it NP-complete? Is it efficiently solvable? Is this a known problem in coding theory?

Also, it is interesting to know the time-complexity of a variant in which vectors $R$ and $C$ contains the integer sum of the one's in each row and column in $A$.

**EDIT**: It is interesting to note that the Sum problem becomes $NP$-complete if the directed graph is required to be acyclic (see the link in Yuval's answer).

Comment: When you are given the actual sums, this is a known as the [digraph realization problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraph_realization_problem).

Comment: For the parity problem, you need the sum of row parities and column parities to be the same, and this probably suffices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Parity problem

It is clear that $\sum_i R_i \equiv \sum_j C_j \pmod{2}$ must hold if any solution exists. On the other hand, if this holds then some solution exists. Let $R$ contain $a$ ones, and let $C$ contain $b$ ones. We can assume without loss of generality that $a \geq b$. Arrange the rows and the columns so that
$$
\begin{align*}
&(R_1,C_1) = \cdots = (R_{n-a},C_{n-a}) = (0,0) \\
&(R_{n-a+1},C_{n-a+1}) = \cdots = (R_{n-b},C_{n-b}) = (1,0) \\
&(R_{n-b+1},C_{n-b+1}) = \cdots = (R_n,C_n) = (1,1)
\end{align*}
$$
Note that there is an even number of occurrences of the second type. We now construct a block diagonal matrix with the following blocks:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0
\end{pmatrix}
 \times (n-a), \quad
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\times (a-b), \quad
\begin{pmatrix}
1
\end{pmatrix}
\times b
$$

## Sum problem

When the actual sums are given, we have the [digraph realization problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraph_realization_problem), which can be solved efficiently.

Comment: Have a look at my follow-up question.  http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/62937/how-hard-is-recovering-an-invertible-binary-matrix-from-its-check-sums