# How hard is recovering an invertible binary matrix from its check sums?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity

This is a follow-up question on my previous one, [How hard is recovering a binary matrix from its check sums?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/62899/how-hard-is-recovering-a-binary-matrix-from-its-check-sums).  Consider the following problem, which adds an extra restriction that the matrix be invertible:

**Parity Problem**

**INPUT**: Two vectors $R_{n*1}$ and $C_{1*n}$.

**QUESTION**: Is there an **invertible** binary matrix $A_{n*n}$ such that vector $R$ contains the parity check of each row in $A$ and vector $C$ contains the parity check of each column in $A$?

The parity check of a row (or column) is the sum of all bits Mod 2 (XOR operation).

> What is the time complexity of the Parity problem? Is it NP-complete? Is it efficiently solvable?

I care about invertibility over GF(2).  A square matrix is *invertible* (over GF(2)) if and only if it has non-zero determinant (after reducing modulo 2).

Comment: @D.W. Thanks for your helpful suggestions. I think the parity problem should be hard for any non-trivial matrix property which is _independent_ of row (columns ) parity. I am looking for coding theory problem that would lead to straightforward reduction.

Comment: @D.W.  The yellow box says: _What is the complexity of the Parity problem?_

Comment: OK.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  What kinds of algorithms have you considered?  What progress have you made so far, and where have you gotten stuck?  Can you find a randomized algorithm for this problem?  Have you tried computing the probability that if you randomly choose a matrix, out of all that are consistent with the parity sums, it will be independent?